# Checkbox is not selected after comparison with an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array containing an object. I would like to have a checkbox marked when the object appears in the array. But my checkbox is not marked, see picture.Only the name is displayed as a chip in the select field. I do not know why

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please may you add a text-based [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The js `includes` function is comparing items with the `===` operator and this doesn't work with objects.

for exmaple the following expression will return `false` :

```js
{id:1} === {id:1}
```

---

To solve your problem you can use the js [function some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) that check if one element of the array match the condition

To compare your object you can either write your logic in the some function or write another function to compare your items.

*Note*: In my opinion, in your case, you can only compare the identifier of the objects to check if they are included in the `personNamen` array

```js
checked={personNamen.some(person => person.name === name.name)}
```

---

### Small example

```js
const personNamen = [{
  name: "Foo", id: 1
}]

const name = {
  name: "Foo", id: 1
}

const name2 = {
  name: "Bar", id: 2
}

const compareObjects = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return obj1.name === obj2.name && obj1.id === obj2.id
}

console.log(personNamen.some(person => compareObjects(person, name))) //true
console.log(personNamen.some(person => compareObjects(person, name2)))  //false
```

---

## Alternating solution

Another solution would be to map the array to the value of the identifier and check if the id is included in the mapped array

Example :

```js
const personNamen = [
  {id: 1, name: "Foo"},
  {id: 2, name: "Bar"},
]

const reduceArray = personNamen.map(x => x.id)

const name1 = {id:1, name: "Foo"}
const name2 = {id:3, name: "Baz"}

console.log(reduceArray.includes(name1.id)) //true
console.log(reduceArray.includes(name2.id)) //false
```